# UWP: How to map arbitrary data to Telerik RadDataGrid

Tags: datagrid, uwp, telerik

So I have a situation in which I am receiving a collection of Dictionary(string, string) entries where the key of each entry is the column name & value the, well, value. I want to push these to a RadDataGrid so that each dictionary maps to a row. If I knew what/how many columns I'd be getting in advance, I'd just map them to an object and have done with it. Unfortunately, it could be different every time, so that won't work.

So far I'm having no luck. I've tried mapping it*(the collection) directly, converting it to dynamic objects & XMLDocument, none of which worked. Also just got the Fall Creators Update & tried mapping it to a DataTable, no luck there either.

I've been experimenting with mapping the DataTable's DefaultView to the grid's ItemsSource after manually adding columns, but while I get the right # of columns and headers, I still don't get the field values. Not sure where to go next.

Mind you, I'm not married to Telerik. If someone else knows a suitably usable UWP data grid solution that will let me map arbitrary data like this, I'd love to hear about it.

Example using a standard UWP app:

MainPage.xaml:

```
<Page xmlns:my="using:Telerik.UI.Xaml.Controls.Grid"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:TestTelerikDataGrid"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:ComponentModel="using:System.ComponentModel" 
    x:Class="TestTelerikDataGrid.MainPage"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" Margin="0,0,0,125">
        <my:RadDataGrid Margin="0,0,0,-125" x:Name="dataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >

        </my:RadDataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

And the back-end:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;

// The Blank Page item template is documented at https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=402352&clcid=0x409

namespace TestTelerikDataGrid {
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page {

        private ObservableCollection<Dictionary<string, string>> items = new ObservableCollection<Dictionary<string, string>>();

        public ObservableCollection<Dictionary<string, string>> ItemDictionary {
            get {
                return items;
            }
            set {
                items = value;
            }
        }

        public DataTable Items { get; set; }

        public MainPage() {

            this.InitializeComponent();

            CreateItems(); // creates sample data structurally identical to what we'll get in the actual app (i.e., obsv. collection of dictionaries)
            CreateTable(); // attempt to take the collection created above and map it to the RadDataGrid
        }

        private void CreateItems() {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                Dictionary<string, string> row = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                row["A"] = "A" + i.ToString();
                row["B"] = "B" + i.ToString();
                row["C"] = "C" + i.ToString();

                ItemDictionary.Add(row);

            }
        }

        private void CreateTable() {
            Items = new DataTable();

            if (ItemDictionary.Count == 0) return;

            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> entry in ItemDictionary[0]) {
                DataColumn column = new DataColumn(entry.Key);
                Items.Columns.Add(column);
                Telerik.UI.Xaml.Controls.Grid.DataGridTextColumn dgc = new Telerik.UI.Xaml.Controls.Grid.DataGridTextColumn();
                dgc.Name = entry.Key;
                dgc.Header = entry.Key;
                dgc.PropertyName = entry.Key;
                dataGrid.Columns.Add(dgc);
            }

            foreach (Dictionary<string, string> rowEntry in ItemDictionary) {
                DataRow row = Items.NewRow();
                int col = 0;
                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> entry in rowEntry) {
                    row[entry.Key] = entry.Value;
                }
                Items.Rows.Add(row);
            }
            DataView dv = Items.DefaultView;
            dataGrid.ItemsSource = dv;
        }
    }
}
```

Ideally, this will result in a table with 5 rows, 3 columns (A, B, C) and the fields showing the correct value (e.g., first row reading A0, B0, C0).

Comment: After reading your long description, I still didn't know what you have done? Could you please provide a [mcve]?

Comment: What's the `DataTable`, `DataColumn`, `DataRow`, `DataView`? Have you installed other libraries for your project?

Comment: Those are all part of UWP 2.0 that came with the Fall Creators Update. I believe it's build 16299 or something like that. Sorry, should have mentioned that's the build I'm using.

Answer (score 0):

> I've been experimenting with mapping the DataTable's DefaultView to the grid's ItemsSource after manually adding columns, but while I get the right # of columns and headers, I still don't get the field values. Not sure where to go next.
>
> Those are all part of UWP 2.0 that came with the Fall Creators Update. I believe it's build 16299 or something like that. Sorry, should have mentioned that's the build I'm using.

The RaDataGrid doesn't support setting DataTable or DataView as ItemsSource directly. You need to cast to an IEnumerble collection instead of DataView.

Please see this thread on Telerik forum for more details: [binding-dictionary-to-raddatagrid](https://www.telerik.com/forums/binding-dictionary-to-raddatagrid#zdg0qI_tP0K26RbdLsmAEw)

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I wound up creating a generic "GridRow" class with properties "Item00"..."Item99" and just mapped the data to that instead. It's a pill but it works. Just putting this here for the next person.

```
public class GridRow {
        public Int32 Index { get; set; }
        public string Item00 { get; set; }
        public string Item01 { get; set; }
        public string Item02 { get; set; }
...etc
}

public ObservableCollection<GridRow> GridData { get; set; }
```

And here's how you populate that:

```
 GridData = new ObservableCollection<GridRow>();
            foreach (Dictionary<string, string> record in ViewModel.ItemsSource) {
                GridRow gridRow = new GridRow();
                gridRow.Index = rowIndex;
                colIndex = 0;
                foreach (DataGridHeader header in ViewModel.Headers) {
                    gridRow.GetType().GetProperty(string.Format("Item{0:D2}", colIndex)).SetValue(gridRow, record[header.Name]);
                    colIndex += 1;
                }
                GridData.Add(gridRow);
                rowIndex += 1;
            }
```

You get the idea.